# hector mapping with fixed laser scanner

Tags: imu, navigation, mapping, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone

I want to use hector_mapping for my robot to do SLAM in uneven terrains. But i am not sure i can use this package if i dont have a stabilizer mechanism for my laser scanner. I mean can i use it just with laser scanner which is fixed in its place and an IMU data?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204724/hector-mapping-with-fixed-laser-scanner/) by [mohammad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19955/mohammad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2015-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes you can, the quality of results will depend on the magnitude of the roll/pitch motion of your robot however (if the scans contain not enough information due to looking at ground or sky, things might fail). For a explanation of how to set things up, see [SettingUpForYourRobot](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam/Tutorials/SettingUpForYourRobot) or some prior questions here ( [1](http://answers.ros.org/question/37344/tf-setting-for-hector-mapping-rollpitch-angle/), [2](http://answers.ros.org/question/40414/setting-up-tf-for-hector-slam/)).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mohammad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19955/mohammad/) on 2015-03-11**:
Thanks for your usefull answer. I have one another qustion. Do we really need IMU datas to use hector_mapping? because i cant see a topic which is for IMU message. I am getting a little confused on this:(